# Every point in the interior of a $n$-dimensional cone can be written as a positive combination of $n$ elements of this cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

This is one of those questions that make sense, but may be hard to prove.

Let $C$ be a *nonempty closed convex pointed cone* in a $n$-dimensional linear space $X$.

Also, assume that $int(C)\neq \emptyset$, so $span(C)=X$.

**Motivation:** A result by Fenchel (Lecture notes 1951, Thm. 7) tells us that any nonzero $x\in C$ can be written in the form $x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i x_i$ for some linearly independent vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in C$ and some nonnegative scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$.

**My question:** Now, then let $x\in int(C)$. Is the following also true?

> There exist linearly independent vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in C$ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i$, where $\alpha_i>0$, $\forall i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

That is, can we always find such a representation with $n$ strictly positive coefficients, for interior points of $C$?

Thank you!

**Reference:** https://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/Fenchel1951.pdf

**Edit:** Added "pointed" after a counterexample by @copper.hat.

Comment: If $x \neq 0$ then since $x \in C$ you have $x=1 \cdot x$. If $n=1$ and you take the $C=\mathbb{R}$ then $x=0$ cannot be written in the above fashion.

Comment: @copper.hat You're right in your second statement, my question was not well formulated. I just added an assumption that $C$ is pointed as well, so $0\notin int(C)$. About your first statement, note that we're looking for a combination of exactly $n$ l.i. points of $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Note that the set $$S^{n-1}=\left\{\sum\alpha_ix_i\mid\alpha_i\ge0,\;\sum\alpha_i=1\right\}$$ is the affine $(n-1)$-simplex with vertices $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). If we let some of the $\alpha_i$'s be $0$ then we get a set of the same form where we have basically ignored some of the $x_i$'s, in other words we get a lower dimensional simplex $S^{n-m-1}$ (where $m$ is the number of $\alpha_i$'s which are zero. Crucially note that $S^{n-1}$ is the convex hull of the set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, and $S^{n-m-1}$ lies entirely in its boundary.

Now, given that your choice of $x$ is in the *interior* of $C$, the set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ can be chosen such that $x$ lies in the *interior* of the cone $$\mathbb{R}^{\ge0}S^{n-1}=\left\{\sum\alpha_ix_i\mid\alpha_i\ge0\right\}.$$ But from what I said above, the interior of this cone is exactly the set $$\left\{\sum\alpha_ix_i\mid\alpha_i\gneq0\right\}.$$

### Edit

The slightly underhand part of my answer above is that I did not justify

> the set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ can be chosen such that $x$ lies in the *interior* of the cone $$\mathbb{R}^{\ge0}S^{n-1}=\left\{\sum\alpha_ix_i\mid\alpha_i\ge0\right\}.$$

so let me do that explicitly. The point $x$ is in the interior of of $C$, so let $B=B(x,\varepsilon)$ be a closed ball centred on $x$ contained in $C$, and let $\partial B=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be its boundary. There are $n$ points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ which define an $(n-1)$-simplex $S^{n-1}$ containing $x$ in its interior (and clearly $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ must be linearly independent since they are not co-hyperplanar).

Comment: Hey, thank you! I was trying to follow the same path as you, but the hard part for me was to prove that "the set $\{x_i\}^n_{i=1}$ can be chosen such that x lies in the interior of the cone $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} S^n$". If there's no such simplex, then $x$ must be at the boundary of $C$, right? But how can we prove that? I also added the "pointed" assumption so $x=0$ is not an interior point of $C$.

Comment: I realised I got the dimension of the simplex wrong, so I fixed that, and added justification of the point you queried. Is that now convincing?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It's really a pity that I cannot accept more than one answer, since the other one is also really good.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $x \in C^\circ$, note that $x \neq 0$. Let $L= \{x\}^\bot$ be the $n-1$ dimensional subspace orthogonal to $x$. Let $b_1,...,b_{n-1}$ be an orthogonal basis for $L$ and note that
$0 = b_1+\cdots+b_{n-1} + b_n$ where $b_n=(-1) (b_1+\cdots+b_{n-1})$ (note that the $b_k$ are affinely independent).
Choose $\epsilon$ such that $x+\epsilon b_k \in C^\circ$ and note that
the points $x+\epsilon b_k$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, this is really clever.